# Android studio not detecting device - Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos

A while ago, I was able to connect my device and have it be detected on Android Studio. But now that's no longer the case.  I've tried it with two separate phones and ADB is unable to detect either of them. After doing some research, I've tried a couple of things:

*Enabled USB debugging

*ADB kill-server/start-server

*Switching phone from MTP to PTP

*Switching USB ports/cables.

Is there anything else that might be useful to try that I haven't tried?

Thanks!

-T

Comment: Have you enabled developer options and "enable USB debugging" options in your devices?

Comment: @AjilO. Yep.  Just updated my post

Comment: You have to use `Connect to PC software` option

Comment: download this http://adbdriver.com/downloads/  and download related drivers of your device.let me know if stuck anywhere.

Comment: @Radhey OP did mention he is using Mac OSX

Comment: Sorry @AjilO. ,its my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device and select `Connect to PC Software` option. `MTP` and `PTP` won't work.

**Edit**:
If you are using a Samsung Galaxy device you might have to use a powered USB hub as suggested in this [post](http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/)

Comment: where is that setting?  I'm not seeing it under development options.  Also, I'm on Mac

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: Currently the Galaxy S7 Edge

Comment: Coincidentally, just now realized that it's most likely an issue with two of my USB cords.  Found a third one and it's starting like a champ.  Thank you for looking into this though.